# Why my navbar has no background color and vertical list?

Tags: codeigniter, bootstrap-4

I'm currently making a website using bootstrap 4 and CodeIgniter as backend. But the navigation bar went weird for some reason.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIBc3.png) (I still don't have enough point to post picture)

There's no navbar color and not to mention, the list is vertical, not horizontal.

This is my code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Code Igniter Blog</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bootswatch.com/4/flatly/bootstrap.min.css">

    </head>
    <body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>">CI Blog</a>
            </div>
            <div id="navbar">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/about">About</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Edit:

I was following a CodeIgniter tutorial by Traversy Media on youtube. I have followed all the steps, except the navbar went weird.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I752ofYu7ag

Comment: Please [read the documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/components/navbar/) before asking questions. There is no `navbar-inverse` in Bootstrap 4, and the Navbar needs the correct structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just go to this link https://bootswatch.com/flatly/

copy source code from this link

Here Your Solution:-

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Code Igniter Blog</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bootswatch.com/4/flatly/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>

    </head>
    <body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>">CI Blog</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarColor02" aria-controls="navbarColor02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarColor02">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/about">About</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>
</html>
```